# write vigenere square in 1d array

Tags: c, for-loop, vigenere

How can i write the vigenere square in a 1d array using these for loops.
I have tried for ages and I just can't work it out. I have a for loop for the column and height. I have a dedicated array for the alphabet called alphab and an array to store the values which has size 26*26.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void vigsq(char *vs);

char *pVs;
char vs[100]; // 1d array of fixed size. vs = vigenere square containing 26 X 26 elements
char alphab[26]; //holds the alphabet in uppercase

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("Hello\n");
    pVs = vs;

    vigsq(pVs);
    return 0;
}


void vigsq(char *vs)
{
    int i = 0;//i index
    int a = 0;//a index

    for (i = 0; i <= 25; i++) // number of row
    {
        for (a = 0; a <= 25 ; a++) // prints the columns a - z
        {

            alphab[a] = (65 + a + i);
            if (alphab[a] > 90)
            {
                alphab[a] = (65 + i);
            }

            printf("|%c|",vs[a]);
        }
        printf("\n"); // print new line
    }

    printf("\n"); // print new line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use modulus operator `%`, this makes sure character stays in range between A to Z.

```
char c = 'A' + shift % 26;
```

You can shift letters to the right, then once letter reaches Z, the next letter will be A

```
int main()
{
    int row, col;
    for (row = 0; row < 26; row++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col < 26; col++)
        {
            char c = 'A' + (row + col) % 26;
            printf("%c ", c);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```